# Functional components: what does this instantiation mean?

Tags: reactjs

Looking through some examples from a library and I noticed the following:

```
const { addToast } = useToast();
```

See below for full picture. I'm not sure what this is trying to achieve and how it would look like in a React component class. If someone could shed some light or point me to the right direction, I would much appreciate it!

```
import {
  Notification,
  Title,
  Close,
  ToastProvider,
  useToast
} from '@zendeskgarden/react-notifications';

...

const Toasts = () => {
  const { addToast } = useToast();

  const handleClick = useCallback(
    (placement: 'top-start' | 'top' | 'top-end' | 'bottom-start' | 'bottom' | 'bottom-end') => {
      return () => {
        addToast(
          ({ close }) => (
            <Notification type="info" style={{ maxWidth: 450 }}>
              <Title>Info</Title>
              Turnip greens yarrow ricebean cauliflower sea lettuce kohlrabi amaranth water
              <Close aria-label="Close" onClick={close} />
            </Notification>
          ),
          { placement }
        );
      };
    },
    [addToast]
  );

......
}
```

Understand syntax and concepts

Comment: This is explained in the [documentation](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/reusing-logic-with-custom-hooks).

Comment: as motioned better is to look in the docs